# Trying to get computer to guess my number but get upper and lower limits to work

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <time.h> 

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL)); // initiates random number generation
    int CpuGuess;
    int IsCorrect;
    int HigherLower;
    int lower,higher;


    printf("Think of a number from 1-9, keep it in mind.\n");
   
    CpuGuess = rand() % 10; //cpu guesses number between 1-9

    printf("Is your number %d? Yes = 1, No = 2, Enter here: ", CpuGuess);
    scanf("%d",&IsCorrect);  // asks if its 1 or 2 depending if correct or false

    while(IsCorrect == 2)
    {
        
        printf("Is your number higher or lower?, lower = 1, higher = 2");
        scanf("%d",&HigherLower);


        if(HigherLower==1)
        {
            lower == 0;
            higher = CpuGuess;
            CpuGuess = (rand() % (higher - lower+1)) + lower;
            printf("Is your number %d?", CpuGuess);
        }
        else if(HigherLower==2)
        {



        }

    }

    if(IsCorrect == 1)
    {

        printf("I have guessed your number!");

    }

}
```

Cant get the guess to be between the higher bound and lower bound its guessing ridiculous number s like 460 and stuff like that and the more i say lower it goes down but only to a certain point and its different each time(still 400+)

Comment: `CpuGuess = rand() % 10; //cpu guesses number between 1-9` - no, it's between `0` and `9`.

Comment: Ah yes my bad, know how to fix the problem though?

Comment: `lower == 0`  - This is not an assign statement, its a comparison, and then you are trying to add up the  `lower ` into the  `CpuGuess ` variable... But  `lower ` is actually uninitialized so I believe this is causing your guesses to be that high, as you have no idea what value the  `lower ` actually has.

Comment: Yep got everything working thanks for the replies :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so as I have already commented, the problem seems to be with `lower == 0`. This is a comparison, not an assignment, so at this point, the `lower` variable is never initialized, and thus if you execute `CpuGuess = (rand() % (higher - lower+1)) + lower;` the lower variable creates undefined behaviour as we have no idea, what value that variable actually has.

Simple fix is to change `lower == 0;` to `lower = 0;` and it should work fine.